# Changing the AdMob base country

Tags: admob

I have an AdMob account for my mobile apps that I opened when I was out of USA. Now I am in USA and want to convert my earnings into US dollars. I came to know that, there is no way that I can convert my account to USA. So I created a new AdMob account with base country USA. However after few days I got email from google saying I cannot have two AdMob accounts. So I closed the old one which was with new email address.

My question is, can I close the out of USA AdMob account and reopen a new AdMob account with the same email address but with base country USA?

Comment: did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: No.. I think I need to close one account and open another one. I read on the internet I will have to wait 90 days to open another account :-(

Comment: That's not good. I think google needs to come up with a solution to this problem. Anyways, good luck!